# How to check object has some property/object in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have to check

```
if (!window.MSStream) ...
```

but I get error in TypeScript, intellisense underlines MSStream object, because it is not declared - and that's exactly my point to check - but I can't build app in Angular2 because of that error.
How can I "cheat" typescript or force him not to be so strict and act like regular javascript and just do that check and leave me alone...

Answer (score 3):

`MSStream` is not part of the type definitions provided for `window`.
You can either add this type on your own or you access this property via square brackets. Then the typescript compiler should be fine.

```
if (!window['MSStream']) { /* do something */ }
```

Comment: You're right, it worked! Although I was SURE I tried that before... obviously I didn't :)

Comment: I know what you mean. :-)
Sometimes I run into the same issues. ;-)
Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

```js
if (!window['MSStream']) { /* do something */ }
```

doesn't work anymore. I get

```js
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.
```

But this works:

```js
(window as Window & {MSStream?: { /* props go here */}}).propXYZ
```

Comment: Wow! This really looks opposite of elegant. Well, thanks for the info

Comment: @Dalibor well the beauty is in the eye of the beholder :) Type-safety comes at a cost here. But it DOES make your intentions more explicit.